# How to write a code to display a page with photo, text and and name

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So far I made an API that calls all the photos and titles inside grid boxes from a database (MongoDB). I made an empty array inside constructor (props) {super(props); this.state ={item[ ] }; And then mapped it inside of these grid boxes with (el=> { return (   ). My question is now when I got all of these how do I make when I press on one box to display me the image, text and name, cause I can't use mapping here, cause this ain't an array.

I used this for find the id of the one photo in my DB, when I access only 1. How do i dipsly it with text and title

```
router.get("/photo/:id", (req, res) => {
Slike.findById(req.params.id, (err, result) => {
res.send(result);
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

instead if using res.send(result); we can use res.render('photo', { url: 'result' });

photo is the template file (like HTML, JSX, pug etc)
react example:-

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'jsx')
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine())
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
res.render('about', { name: 'Flavio' })
})
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server ready'))
```

for more details https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html